# I got Error BC30663 Attribute 'TargetFrameworkAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a project vb.net was working correctly
today I opened the project I got this error:
BC30663 Attribute 'TargetFrameworkAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times

I followed most solutions that I found here and on other sites but I couldn't solve.
this is a strange problem because it wasn't before

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this while converting an old VB website to a web application.  The output 'obj' folder was included in the solution.  I removed the 'obj' folder from the solution by right clicking on it and selecting 'Exclude from Project'.  I was able to compile after that.